# mysql insert with conditions

Tags: mysql, insert, conditional-statements

I have a mysql database and a form that inserts stuff into it. I would like to prevent adding a row if there was a row where the `Status` column equaled "New" or "Redeploy" and is the same $tag (which is what they are entering in to the area of the form)

Basically i want to prevent people from adding a entry if that $tag already was there with a status of "new" or "redeploy". kind of hard to explain

here is my current query  any assistance or ideas would be appreciated.

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO Assets (`Badge`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Service Tag`, `Asset Tag`, `Status`, `Employee Status`, `Username`, `deleted`)
                     VALUES('$badge', '$first', '$last', '$tag', '$asset', '$status', '$estatus', '$user', '$deleted') ") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use a check constraint on the table. That way your condition will always be enforced, no matter how the insert/update is made.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

For something like this you'd probably want to create a function as well. So your function would look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckAssetRows(@Tag VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumInvalidRows INT

    SELECT @NumInvalidRows = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Asset 
    WHERE [Service Tag]=@Tag
    AND [Status] in ('New', 'Redeploy')

    RETURN @NumInvalidRows
END
GO
```

And your check is easy:

```
ALTER TABLE ASSET
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Tag CHECK(CheckAssetRows([Service Tag]) = 0)
```

Comment: My edit should help to get you started. Nothing is tested, I just threw it together.

Comment: I am still struggling keeps giving improper syntax trying to create the funciton.  With several modifications I was able to get it to say "#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function"  any additional advice? :)